# Node.js Q promises, why use defer() when you can use this()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, deferred, promise

I wanted to do something like:

```
somePromiseFunc(value1)
.then(function(value2, callback) {
    // insert the next then() into this function:
    funcWithCallback(callback);
})
.then(function(dronesYouAreLookingFor){
    // Have a party
})
.done();
```

---

It didn't work. I couldn't get it to work. I was advised to use `defer()` for this purpose.

Their [own docs](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#using-deferreds) say we should use deferreds for callback-style functions. Although this is confusing because their famous *flatten the pyramid* example is all about callbacks, but the example is too abstract to follow.

Hence, I see a lot of people using `defer`s and that is what I did:

```
somePromiseFunc(value1)
.then(function(value2) {
    var promise = q.defer();

    funcWithCallback(function(err, dronesYouAreLookingFor){
        if (!err)
            promise.resolve(dronesYouAreLookingFor);
        else
            promise.reject(new Error(err));
    });
    return promise.promise;
})
.then(function(dronesYouAreLookingFor){
    // Have a party
})
.done();
```

---

Until I found out through examining source code that this also works:

```
somePromiseFunc(value1)
.then(function(value2) {
    return function() {
        funcWithCallback(arguments[1]);
    };
})
.then(function(dronesYouAreLookingFor){
    // Have a party
})
.done();
```

Why should I not use this much simpler undocumented version?

Undocumented, because although this looks like what *flatten the pyramid* does, `return function(){withCB(arguments[1])}` works while `return function(err, cb){withCB(cb)}` does not.

Comment: I think they're just showing you how to convert callback style functions to use promises with `defer`, and the more explicit example makes it clearer what all the arguments are. A promise can be returned, stored in a data structure, and arbitrarily composed with other promises. That's (part of) the whole point of promises. If you have a special case that's shorter w/o them, by all means use that. But if you refactor later, you might need to convert it to a promise; that's all.

Comment: But if wrapping a function in a returned function is a legal way to insert `then()` into the callback, wouldn't they have documented this?
More specifically, undocumented `return function(){withCB(arguments[1])}` works but `return function(err, cb){withCB(cb)}` does not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not a legal way of using a promise library.  As detailed in [the promises spec](http://promises-aplus.github.com/promises-spec/) that Q aims to comply with, anything you return from a `.then` callback that is not a promise should be passed directly through.

Essentially callback based code should be treated as `legacy` when you're using promises.

You have two basic options.  If you use funcWithCallback lots of times you can do something like:

```
var promisedFunc = Q.nfbind(funcWithCallback);

somePromiseFunc(value1)
.then(function(value2) {
    return promisedFunc();
})
.then(function(dronesYouAreLookingFor){
    // Have a party
})
.done();
```

or if you need to pass arguments:

```
var promisedFunc = Q.nfbind(funcWithCallback);

somePromiseFunc(value1)
.then(function(value2) {
    return promisedFunc(value1, value2);
})
.then(function(dronesYouAreLookingFor){
    // Have a party
})
.done();
```

If you're only using it once you can do

```
somePromiseFunc(value1)
.then(function(value2) {
    return Q.nfcall(funcWithCallback);
})
.then(function(dronesYouAreLookingFor){
    // Have a party
})
.done();
```

or if you need to pass arguments:

```
somePromiseFunc(value1)
.then(function(value2) {
    return Q.nfcall(funcWithCallback, value1, value2);
})
.then(function(dronesYouAreLookingFor){
    // Have a party
})
.done();
```